# Find new, left and existing records in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with data like this

[image]

I want to compare each record with next year's record and see if that id is there. If it's there in the year and the next year it's 'Existing', If it's there in the year and not there in the next year, it's 'Left'. If it's not there in the year but there in the next year, it's 'New'. I want output like this below. The columns 2017-18, 2018-19 etc. should be created dynamically.

How do I achieve this?

[image]

After getting the data in the above format, I need to aggregate the sales for each year band like this as below. For example for 2017-2018,

New_sales = sum of all sales of 2018 (which is the later year in 2017-2018) where it's marked as 'New' which is 25 here.

Left_sales = sum of all sales of 2017 (the earlier year in 2017-2018) where it's marked as 'Left' which is 100 here.

Existing_sales = sum of sales of 2017 where it's marked as 'Existing' subtract sum of sales of 2018 where it's marked as 'Existing'

Existing_sales = 50+75 (sales of 2017, 'Existing') - (20+50) (sales of 2018, 'Existing') = 125-70 = 55

How do I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `date` is a string, I think you can:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[
        (1, '31/12/2017'),
        (2, '31/12/2017'),
        (3, '31/12/2017'),
        (1, '31/12/2018'),
        (3, '31/12/2018'),
        (5, '31/12/2018'),
    ],
    schema=['id', 'date']
)
```

First you can get the year first:

```
df2 = df.withColumn('year', func.split(func.col('Date'), '/').getItem(2))
df2.show(10, False)

+---+----------+----+
|id |date      |year|
+---+----------+----+
|1  |31/12/2017|2017|
|2  |31/12/2017|2017|
|3  |31/12/2017|2017|
|1  |31/12/2018|2018|
|3  |31/12/2018|2018|
|5  |31/12/2018|2018|
+---+----------+----+
```

Then you can collect the list of year by `id` as a reference:

```
df3 = df2.groupby('id')\
    .agg(func.collect_set('year').alias('year_lst'))
df3.show(3, False)

+---+------------+
|id |year_lst    |
+---+------------+
|1  |[2017, 2018]|
|2  |[2017]      |
|3  |[2017, 2018]|
+---+------------+
```

Then you can join the reference back to the data:

```
df4 = df2.join(df3, on='id', how='left')
df4.show(10, False)

+---+----------+----+------------+
|id |date      |year|year_lst    |
+---+----------+----+------------+
|1  |31/12/2017|2017|[2017, 2018]|
|2  |31/12/2017|2017|[2017]      |
|3  |31/12/2017|2017|[2017, 2018]|
|1  |31/12/2018|2018|[2017, 2018]|
|3  |31/12/2018|2018|[2017, 2018]|
|5  |31/12/2018|2018|[2018]      |
+---+----------+----+------------+
```

The last step is to create the column dynamically. I think you can use a for loop:

```
year_loop = ['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021']

for idx in range(len(year_loop)-1):
    this_year = year_loop[idx]
    next_year = year_loop[idx+1]
    column_name = f"{this_year}-{next_year}"

    new_condition = (~func.array_contains(func.col('year_lst'), this_year)) & (func.array_contains(func.col('year_lst'), next_year))
    exist_condition = (func.array_contains(func.col('year_lst'), this_year)) & (func.array_contains(func.col('year_lst'), next_year))
    left_condition = (func.array_contains(func.col('year_lst'), this_year)) & (~func.array_contains(func.col('year_lst'), next_year))

    df4 = df4.withColumn(column_name, func.when(new_condition, func.lit('New'))
                                          .when(exist_condition, func.lit('Existing'))
                                          .when(left_condition, func.lit('Left')))

df4.show(10, False)

+---+----------+----+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|id |date      |year|year_lst    |2017-2018|2018-2019|2019-2020|2020-2021|
+---+----------+----+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|1  |31/12/2017|2017|[2017, 2018]|Existing |Left     |null     |null     |
|2  |31/12/2017|2017|[2017]      |Left     |null     |null     |null     |
|3  |31/12/2017|2017|[2017, 2018]|Existing |Left     |null     |null     |
|1  |31/12/2018|2018|[2017, 2018]|Existing |Left     |null     |null     |
|3  |31/12/2018|2018|[2017, 2018]|Existing |Left     |null     |null     |
|5  |31/12/2018|2018|[2018]      |New      |Left     |null     |null     |
+---+----------+----+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, thank you so much for the detailed answer. I see that you have hard coded the values in year_loop in your code above. year_loop = ['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021'] 
Is there any way if it can be passed dynamically without hard coding the years?

Comment: Hi @sparc, if you just want to do the `year` that appear in the data, you can collect this list by `year_loop = [str(row['year']) for row in df2.select('year').distinct().orderBy('year').collect()]`

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan for your help.  I want to create a new dataframe to create aggregated values for each year bands-
2017-2018, 
2018-2019,2019-2020,2020-2021 etc. How do I create a new column in a new dataframe with year_loop values?

Comment: Hi @sparc, not sure if I understand your question correctly, you want to consider `2017-2018`, `2018-2019` ... as the value of the column so that you can use the grouping and do some aggregation? If so, you should not put `2017-2018`, `2018-2019` as your column. If you really need to create the new dataframe based on the above dataframe, you might need to do `union` of your dataframe.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, sorry for the confusion.  The code that you have given for the previous dataframe worked perfectly fine.  Now, I have to create another dataframe with the aggregated values but 2017-2018,2018-2019 should be the values of one column. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Hi @sparc, I guess you're talking about the unpivot of the dataframe? If yes, you can check this post to see if this helps you: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/how-to-pivot-table-and-unpivot-a-spark-dataframe/. If not, please edit your own post or create a new post and provide some example.

Comment: Hi @Jonthan, I have edited the question and added sales column in there.  I have also added the expected output by year bands with example.  Please can you help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, here is my new question. Please can you help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334455/pyspark-find-new-left-and-existing-sales/73346090#73346090

Comment: Hi @sparc, sorry for the late reply, was busy last week, will check your new post and try to answer today, Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, was waiting to hear from you. Please can you answer my new post as the answer somebody had given was not working for me. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you

Comment: Hi @sparc, I just answer your post, please let me know if it can answer your question.