# Pyspark - Find new, left and existing sales

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe like this

[image]

and I want output like this

[image]

I need to aggregate the sales for each year band like this as below. For example for 2018-2019,

New_sales = sum of all sales of 2019 (which is the later year in 2018-2019) where the id didn't exists in 2018 but exists in 2019

Existing_sales = sum of sales of 2018 where the id is there in 2018 and 2019 subtract sum of sales of 2019

Existing_sales = 50+75 (sales of 2018) - (20+50) (sales of 2019) = 125-70 = 55

Left_sales = sum of all sales of 2018 (the earlier year in 2018-2019) where the id exists in 2018 but not in 2019

How do I achieve that?

Comment: what does df2 actually look like and what values do you want under the df1 columns?

Comment: do you want to transform the first dataframe to look like the second dataframe? i'm not very clear on what you want to achieve. why are A, B, C under `2018-2019` column in the first dataframe?

Comment: Hi @samkart, yes I want to transform the first data frame with aggregated sales  for each year band. The first data frame has columns like 2018-2019, 2019-2020 and so on.  Is it possible to join the dataframes where the value from Years column in second dataframe is matched to one of the columns in other data frame. For e.g. 2018-2019 value from Years column from df2 should be matched to 2018-19 column from df1. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: why do you want to join the 2 dataframes? you can simply create the second one using the first one from scratch

Comment: Hi @samkart, yes that's what I want. Is it possible to do that from the first dataframe?

Comment: can sales be negative? e.g. if 2019 sales is higher than 2018, 2018_sales - 2019_sales will be negative

Comment: Hi @samkart, I have edited my question.   A, B, C that I mentioned before are not product categories.  It's checking if the id is new, left, or existing for 2018-19 and so on....  Please can you have a look and help me, Thanks.

Comment: Hi @samkart, I have edited my question to make it more clear.  Please can you have a look and help

Comment: I've added a new answer which, I think, would be very optimized compared to the existing accepted approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some more dummy data to include 2020 year for this example.

```
# +---+---+----------+
# | id|amt|        dt|
# +---+---+----------+
# |  1| 50|2018-12-31|
# |  2|100|2018-12-31|
# |  3| 75|2018-12-31|
# |  1| 20|2019-12-31|
# |  3| 50|2019-12-31|
# |  5| 25|2019-12-31|
# |  1| 70|2020-12-31|
# |  2|150|2020-12-31|
# |  5|125|2020-12-31|
# +---+---+----------+
```

You can extract the year from the dates and pivot them with the sales values under it. This would make the calculations manageable by reducing the number of rows - Number of years would be less, so calculations would be optimized.

```
yr_sales_sdf = data_sdf. \
    fillna(0, subset=['amt']). \
    withColumn('yr', func.year('dt')). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('yr'). \
    agg(func.first('amt'))

# +---+----+----+----+
# | id|2018|2019|2020|
# +---+----+----+----+
# |  5|null|  25| 125|
# |  1|  50|  20|  70|
# |  3|  75|  50|null|
# |  2| 100|null| 150|
# +---+----+----+----+
```

We'll need the years as a list - This can be extracted from the pivoted dataframe's columns as done in `yrs` list - and a case when function that will calculate if the ID is existing, left or new - I've created `sale_cat_cond` function (*and it is purely pyspark so automatically optimized*) that takes in two consecutive years as columns and checks the condition to generate the category and its sales as a struct. Structs are very helpful to track in these cases where the same condition is checked for more than one required values.

```
yrs = [k for k in yr_sales_sdf.columns if k[0:2] == '20']
sale_cat_cond = lambda frstCol, scndCol: (
    func.when(func.col(frstCol).isNull() & func.col(scndCol).isNotNull(), 
              func.struct(func.lit(frstCol+'-'+scndCol).alias('year_band'), 
                          func.lit('new_sales').alias('salecat'), 
                          func.col(scndCol).alias('sale')
                          )
              ).
    when(func.col(frstCol).isNotNull() & func.col(scndCol).isNull(), 
         func.struct(func.lit(frstCol+'-'+scndCol).alias('year_band'), 
                     func.lit('left_sales').alias('salecat'), 
                     func.col(frstCol).alias('sale')
                     )
         ).
    otherwise(func.struct(func.lit(frstCol+'-'+scndCol).alias('year_band'), 
                          func.lit('existing_sales').alias('salecat'), 
                          (func.col(frstCol)-func.col(scndCol)).alias('sale')
                          )
              )
)
```

Run the `sale_cat_cond` on all year columns, using a list comprehension, to calculate sales categories and their sales. This creates additional columns for all year bands.

```
yr_salecat_sdf = yr_sales_sdf. \
    select('*',
           *[sale_cat_cond(yrs[i], yrs[i+1]).alias(yrs[i]+'_'+yrs[i+1]+'_salecat') for i in range(len(yrs) - 1)]
           )

# +---+----+----+----+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+
# |id |2018|2019|2020|2018_2019_salecat              |2019_2020_salecat                |
# +---+----+----+----+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+
# |5  |null|25  |125 |{2018-2019, new_sales, 25}     |{2019-2020, existing_sales, -100}|
# |1  |50  |20  |70  |{2018-2019, existing_sales, 30}|{2019-2020, existing_sales, -50} |
# |3  |75  |50  |null|{2018-2019, existing_sales, 25}|{2019-2020, left_sales, 50}      |
# |2  |100 |null|150 |{2018-2019, left_sales, 100}   |{2019-2020, new_sales, 150}      |
# +---+----+----+----+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

The only thing left is to pivot-sum the sales categories and their sales. To do this, first collate all year band category structs into an array - This will make it easy to explode and pivot per ID (using SQL's `inline` function).

```
yr_salecat_sdf. \
    withColumn('salecat_struct_arr', 
               func.array(*[k for k in yr_salecat_sdf.columns if '_salecat' in k])
               ). \
    selectExpr('id', 'inline(salecat_struct_arr)'). \
    groupBy('year_band'). \
    pivot('salecat'). \
    agg(func.sum('sale')). \
    show()

# +---------+--------------+----------+---------+
# |year_band|existing_sales|left_sales|new_sales|
# +---------+--------------+----------+---------+
# |2019-2020|          -150|        50|      150|
# |2018-2019|            55|       100|       25|
# +---------+--------------+----------+---------+
```

---

Additional details - schemas for all dataframes

*data_sdf*

```
# root
#  |-- id: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- amt: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- dt: date (nullable = true)
```

*yr_sales_sdf*

```
# root
#  |-- id: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- 2018: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- 2019: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- 2020: long (nullable = true)
```

*yr_salecat_sdf*

```
# root
#  |-- id: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- 2018: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- 2019: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- 2020: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- 2018-2019_salecat: struct (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- year_band: string (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- salecat: string (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- sale: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- 2019-2020_salecat: struct (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- year_band: string (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- salecat: string (nullable = false)
#  |    |-- sale: long (nullable = true)
```

*final result*

```
# root
#  |-- year_band: string (nullable = false)
#  |-- existing_sales: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- left_sales: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- new_sales: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: what should happen in that case? @sparc

Comment: @sparc - but even if it is considered as "existing_sales", nothing is added to it as the sales for that `id` will be null. what issue are you facing exactly and what, according to you, should happen in such a case?

Comment: Hi @samkart, apologies, pls ignore my previous comment. The numbers are different because for example for 2018-2019, if an id has a value in the start year(2018) and NULL in the end year(2019) your code is showing as 'left' whereas it should be 'existing' because the id is still there, it's just that it has no value. Also, if there is NULL in the start year and a value in the end year, code is showing as 'new' but it should be existing. We are saying 'New' or 'left' only if the id is not there atall in that year. It doesn't matter if there is a value or not

Comment: @sparc - null in that year means the ID is not present in that year. because it is a pivot, all ids will have all year fields and null would mean they are not present in that year. are there cases in your input data where the sales is null for a `date` (before the pivot)?

Comment: yes there are nulls in the data before pivot. For 2018-19, if there are nulls in 2019 and data in 2018, it's showing as left

Comment: @sparc - you can fill them with 0 **before the pivot** and the rest conditions will work fine

Comment: Hi @samkart,the code that you have given works perfectly fine and is very quick. Thank you so much for your help. You are a super star.

Answer (score 1):

@Sparc

here is the solution . do let me know if you have questions around this.

```
--Approach--
You can use create two df based on year(date) and then 

do inner join ---> to find the existing sales

df_2018 left_anti with df_2019--> give left_sales

df_2019 left_anti with df_2018 ---> give new sales.

combines these three by union , boom you get the result.
```

kindly upvote if you  like my approach.

```
Solution:-

from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

schema=["id","date_val","sales"]
data =[("1","2018-12-31","50"),                                                                                        
("2","2018-12-31","100"),
("3","2018-12-31","75"),
("1","2019-12-31","20"),
("3","2019-12-31","50"),
("5","2019-12-31","25")]
date_range=["2018","2019"]

df=spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
df= df1.withColumn("date_val",F.col("date_val").cast("date"))\
.withColumn("year",F.year(F.col("date_val")).cast("string"))\
.withColumn("year_bands", F.lit(date_range[0]+"-"+date_range[1]))
filter_cond_2018 = (F.col("year") == "2018")
df_2018=df.filter(filter_cond_2018)
df_2019 = df.filter(~filter_cond_2018)
df_left_sales = df_2018.join(df_2019,["id"],"left_anti")\
.groupBy(["year","year_bands"]).agg(F.sum(F.col("sales")).alias("Left_Sales"))
df_new_sales=df_2019.join(df_2018,["id"],"left_anti")\
.groupBy(["year","year_bands"]).agg(F.sum(F.col("sales")).alias("New_Sales"))
df_ext_sales_2018 = df_2018.join(df_2019,["id"],"inner").select(df_2018["*"])\
.groupBy(["year","year_bands"]).agg(F.sum(F.col("sales")).alias("Existing_Sale_{}".format(date_range[0])))
df_ext_sales_2019 = df_2019.join(df_2018,["id"],"inner").select(df_2019["*"])\
.groupBy(["year","year_bands"]).agg(F.sum(F.col("sales")).alias("Existing_Sale_{}".format(date_range[1])))
df_agg = df_left_sales.join(df_new_sales,["year_bands"])\
.join(df_ext_sales_2018,["year_bands"])\
.join(df_ext_sales_2019,["year_bands"])
df_agg_fnl =df_agg\
.withColumn("Existing_Sales", F.col("Existing_Sale_{}".format(date_range[0]))-F.col("Existing_Sale_{}".format(date_range[1])))\
.select(["year_bands","Left_Sales","New_Sales","Existing_Sales"])
df_agg_fnl.show(10,0)
```

```
Generic Solution :

from pyspark.sql import functions as F ,DataFrame

schema=["id","date_val","sales"]
data =[("1","2018-12-31","50"),                                                                                        
("2","2018-12-31","100"),
("3","2018-12-31","75"),
("1","2019-12-31","20"),
("3","2019-12-31","50"),
("5","2019-12-31","25"),
("6","2020-12-31","25"),
("5","2020-12-31","10"),
("7","2020-12-31","25")]
date_range=["2018","2019"]

df=spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
df = df.withColumn("year",F.split(F.col('date_val'), '-').getItem(0))
year_bands=df.select("year").distinct().toPandas()["year"].tolist()
def calculate_agg_data(df,start_year,end_year):
  df_start_year=df.filter(F.col("year").isin([start_year]))
  df_end_year=df.filter(F.col("year").isin([end_year]))
  df_left_sales = df_start_year.join(df_end_year,["id"],"left_anti")\ .groupBy(["year","year_bands"]).agg(F.sum(F.col("sales")).alias("Left_Sales"))
  df_new_sales=df_end_year.join(df_start_year,["id"],"left_anti")\
  .groupBy(["year","year_bands"]).agg(F.sum(F.col("sales")).alias("New_Sales"))
  df_start_year_ext_sales = df_start_year.join(df_end_year,["id"],"inner").select(df_start_year["*"])\
  .groupBy(["year","year_bands"]).agg(F.sum(F.col("sales")).alias("Existing_Sale_{}".format(start_year)))
  df_end_year_ext_sales = df_end_year.join(df_start_year,["id"],"inner").select(df_end_year["*"])\
  .groupBy(["year","year_bands"]).agg(F.sum(F.col("sales")).alias("Existing_Sale_{}".format(end_year)))
  # final agg 
  df_agg = df_left_sales.join(df_new_sales,["year_bands"])\
  .join(df_start_year_ext_sales,["year_bands"])\
  .join(df_end_year_ext_sales,["year_bands"])
  df_agg_fnl =df_agg\
  .withColumn("Existing_Sales", F.col("Existing_Sale_{}".format(start_year))-F.col("Existing_Sale_{}".format(end_year)))\
  .select(["year_bands","Left_Sales","New_Sales","Existing_Sales"])
  return df_agg_fnl

df_lst=[]
for index in range(len(year_bands)-1):
  start_year=year_bands[index]
  end_year=year_bands[index+1]
  df=df.withColumn("year_bands", F.lit(start_year+"-"+end_year))
  df_flt =df.filter(F.col("year").isin([start_year,end_year]))
  df_agg =calculate_agg_data(df_flt,start_year,end_year)
  df_lst.append(df_agg)

df_fnl = reduce(DataFrame.unionByName,df_lst)
df_fnl.show(10,0)
```

```
Alternative for reduce 

df_fnl=df_lst[0]
for index in range(1,len(df_lst)):
   if len(df_lst)>=1:
      df_fnl=df_fnl.unionByName(df_lst[index])
df_fnl.show(40,0)
```

Kindly upvote of you like my solution and Approach .

([image: run_time of above solution])

Comment: Hi @Deku07, thanks for your reply. Is it possible to make it more dynamic rather than hard coding the years?

Comment: okay let me try that out as well. Would you mind  upvote my answer .

Comment: @sparc already posted the generic solution .Kindly upvote if you like my solution or reach out to me if you have any questions for the same .

Comment: Hi @Deku07, I tried your code but it's taking forever to run.  It timed out after 45 minutes. Is there a way to optimise the code?

Comment: @sparc

how many rows data you have and cluster config?

Comment: Hi @Deku07, I have tried with the sample data that you have got in the dataframe. it's giving this error at the show statement after around 45 mins. Any idea why?
TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled. --> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.. ---> SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

Comment: let me post the same sample run on databricks Spark 3.1  having cluster config single node cluster of 16GB and 2 cores.

it should not be happening .

I have seen you have not upvoted yet .

Comment: Hi @Deku07, I have got 4cores with 32GB. I tried running it again and it's running forever. Any idea how to resolve this?  I will upvote once this is resolved and I get the output.

Comment: Hi @Deku07, what does reduce statement do? Not sure if that's the problem. Is there a way to do union without reduce statement?

Comment: @sparc

you can achieve this without reduce as well .

For cluster could you share what kind of Big data system you are using is it cloud or on prem ?

and the error you showed is related to reading the data . Not sure why you are getting this for the above sample data .s
with the above sample data , i can easily run on 15gb and 2 cores cluster on Databricks.

Comment: Hi @Deku07, I have upvoted you as you put lot of effort in helping me. But still the show statement is running forever and can't see the output, don't know why.

Comment: Hi @Deku07, I think the problem is with caculated_agg_data function, it's taking forever to run. Can we optimise it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247284/discussion-between-deku07-and-sparc).

Answer (score 0):

So based on your previous post we have a dataframe `df` which is

```
+---+----------+----+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|id |date      |year|year_lst    |2017-2018|2018-2019|2019-2020|2020-2021|
+---+----------+----+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|1  |31/12/2017|2017|[2017, 2018]|Existing |Left     |null     |null     |
|2  |31/12/2017|2017|[2017]      |Left     |null     |null     |null     |
|3  |31/12/2017|2017|[2017, 2018]|Existing |Left     |null     |null     |
|1  |31/12/2018|2018|[2017, 2018]|Existing |Left     |null     |null     |
|3  |31/12/2018|2018|[2017, 2018]|Existing |Left     |null     |null     |
|5  |31/12/2018|2018|[2018]      |New      |Left     |null     |null     |
+---+----------+----+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

As you mentioned that you have a `sales` column now which you need to do the aggregation, assume when you use df.columns, your output should look like this:

```
['id', 'date', 'year', 'sales', 'year_lst', '2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2019-2020', '2020-2021']
```

To achieve your goal, what you can do is:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import func

# loop from 2017-2018 column
for idx, year_year in enumerate(df.columns[4:]):
    new_df = df.filter(func.col('year')==year_year.split('-')[0])\
        .select('id', 
                'sales', 
                func.lit(year_year).alias('year_year'),
                func.col(year_year).alias('status'))
    if idx == 0:
        output = new_df
    else:
        output = output.unionAll(new_df)
```

The remain is just the aggregation:

```
output.groupby('year_year').pivot('status').agg(func.sum('sales')).fillna(0).orderBy(func.col('year_year')).show()
```

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, it's giving me error that there is no column called 'year_year' in the last step -output.groupby('year_year').pivot('status').agg(func.sum('sales')).fillna(0).orderBy(func.col('year_year')).show()

Comment: Hi @sparc, I made a mistake and I just update it, it was the issue of the column naming. Please check if it works for you now. Please upvote and accept if this answer helps you. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan. I think there is some problem in the code above in the for loop, it's showing records for 'Existing' and 'left' but not showing any records for 'New'. Unitl before the for loop above it's showing records for all. Somehow 'New' records are being eliminated in the for loop.